# SQL Query to get specific child records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement to get child table records based on parent table search criteria but they need to be distinct and output should be like below:
[image]

Table A, have three rows. Row one is for generic rules, Row 2 is for specific Category and Row 3 is for Specific Branch, Category and Sub-Category.
Now, my output should consists of the rules which are specific to generic.
Below are the rules for the output:

- Input to the query will be Branch, Category and Sub-Category
- Each record-set in Table-A is comprised of 03 rows
  Row 1 has Branch but Category and Sub-Category as Null
  Row 2 has Branch and Category  Sub-Category as Null
  Row 3 has Branch, Category and Sub-Category.
- Each Row in a record-set of Table-A has child records in Table-B
- Record with Branch only (Row 1), have generic records and these records can also be child records of Row 2 and Row 3
- Record with Branch and Category  Sub-Category as Null (Row 2) has child records in Table-B and they are overriding child records of Row 1
- Record with Branch, Category and Sub-Category (Row 3) has child records in Table-B and they are overriding child records of Row 1 and Row 2.
- All child records of Row 1,2 & 3 will be part of the output but if a child is present in Row 3 then despite if it is present in other Rows output will consists of child record of Row 3
- If a child record is present in Row 1 & 2 but not in 3 then output
  will have child record of Row 2
- if a child record is present in Row 1 but not in Row 2 & 3 then it
  will be part of output.

Now,

- In the sample output, 'Pay' is present in Row 1,2 and 3 but in the
  output we are considering child record of Row 3 as it overrides both Record 1 & 2
- 'Discount' is present in Record 1 & 3 but output includes child of Row 3
- 'Items' is not part of Row 1 and Row 2 childs but as it is present in Row 3 so it will be part of output
- 'Paris' is only part of Row 2 but as it is not overriden by Row 2 so
  it is part of output as it is

I have tried following query but it is not giving the required output:

```
SELECT DISTINCT RULE,
                value
FROM   siebel.b rxm
WHERE  par_row_id IN (SELECT row_id
                      FROM   siebel.a
                      WHERE  ( branch = 'Civil'
                               AND category = 'C.M.> (Civil)'
                               AND sub_category IS NULL )
                              OR ( branch = 'Civil'
                                   AND category = 'C.M. (Civil)'
                                   AND sub_category = 'Pauper' )
                              OR ( branch = 'Civil'
                                   AND category IS NULL
                                   AND sub_category IS NULL ))
```

I am using Oracle as RDBMS.

Schema statements:

```
Create Table A (ROW_ID int, BRANCH varchar(50), CATEGORY varchar(50), SUB_CATEGORY varchar(50))
Create Table B (PAR_ROW_ID int, RULE varchar(50), Value varchar(50))

INSERT INTO A (ROW_ID, BRANCH)
VALUES (1,'Civil')
INSERT INTO A (ROW_ID, BRANCH, CATEGORY)
VALUES (2,'Civil','C.M. (Civil)')
INSERT INTO A (ROW_ID, BRANCH, CATEGORY, SUB_CATEGORY)
VALUES (3,'Civil','C.M. (Civil)','Pauper')

INSERT INTO B (PAR_ROW_ID, RULE, VALUE)
VALUES (1,'Pay','10')
INSERT INTO B (PAR_ROW_ID, RULE, VALUE)
VALUES (1','Days','25')
INSERT INTO B (PAR_ROW_ID, RULE, VALUE)
VALUES (1,'Discount','20')
INSERT INTO B (PAR_ROW_ID, RULE, VALUE)
VALUES (2,'Pairs','5')
INSERT INTO B (PAR_ROW_ID, RULE, VALUE)
VALUES (2,'Pay','30')
INSERT INTO B (PAR_ROW_ID, RULE, VALUE)
VALUES (3,'Pay','15')
INSERT INTO B (PAR_ROW_ID, RULE, VALUE)
VALUES (3,'Discount','20')
INSERT INTO B (PAR_ROW_ID, RULE, VALUE)
VALUES (3,'items','30')
```

Comment: (1) Question is not clear. You got to explain the expected output line by line, that on which basis any row is part of your output or not. 

(2) Try to share create/insert statements so we can try replicating. We cannot type each column and row to test the scenarios.

Comment: @Utsav, sorry I could not make my question more clear. I have updated it now and mentioned more detailed description. Hope it will be clear now.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX( par_row_id ) AS par_row_id,
       rule,
       MAX( value ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST OVER ORDER BY par_row_id ) AS value
FROM   table_b
GROUP BY rule
```

Or:

```
SELECT par_row_id,
       rule,
       value
FROM   (
  SELECT b.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY rule ORDER BY par_row_id DESC ) AS rn
  FROM   table_b b
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```