# Getting data based on Priority

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with structure as below:

[image]

'Type' column has three type of values that is 1,2 and 3.

Each Type has certain Rule (mentioned in RULE column)
Same rule can be associated with multiple Type records.
Now I want to get only those records as output which has higher value.
For example:
'Bench Type' is a rule associated with Type 1,2 and 3 so we will pick Rule with Value with Type 3, that is Single.
'Complexity' is with Type 1 & 2 so we will pick rule Value  5.
If a Rule is present in just one Type then it will be picked as it is.

I tried following query but it is working with Type 1 & 2.

```
select *
FROM CX_ROSTER_RULES_VIEW v
INNER JOIN 
(
select RULE, MAX("Type") AS MAX_TYPE
FROM CX_ROSTER_RULES_VIEW
GROUP BY RULE
) v1
ON v.RULE = v1.RULE
AND v."Type" = v1.MAX_TYPE
WHERE ( branch = 'Civil' AND category = 'C.M. (Civil)' AND sub_category = 'Pauper' )        
       OR ( branch = 'Civil' AND category = 'C.M. (Civil)' AND sub_category IS NULL )
        OR ( branch = 'Civil' AND category IS NULL AND sub_category IS NULL )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Query to get specific child records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37571301/sql-query-to-get-specific-child-records)

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice - you can edit your existing question.

Comment: It is different. Previous is from two tables. It is from a single view.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function then you will not need to do a self-join:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT v.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Rule ORDER BY "Type" DESC ) AS rn
  FROM   CX_ROSTER_RULES_VIEW v
  WHERE branch = 'Civil'
  AND   (  category IS NULL 
        OR ( category = 'C.M. (Civil)'
           AND ( sub_category IS NULL OR sub_category = 'Pauper' )
           )
        )
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Comment: It is giving correct output. But it is possible to have a single WHERE clause in whole query?

Comment: @Bill Why? Apart from aesthetic reasons there is no benefit compared to having multiple `WHERE` clauses nested in inline views. Also, it will probably break the query as you need to filter on the branch/category/sub-category before you generate the `ROW_NUMBER()` and then filter on that afterwards. You could try `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Rule, Branch ORDER BY "Type" DESC ) AS rn` and then moving the `WHERE` clause from the inner to the outer select block but I think it may have unintended side-effects and be less performant.

Answer (score 0):

i would do this.

```
(select rule, max(type) as type from yourtable
group by rule) --this will give you the rule with the highest priority
```

with that do this

```
select m.* from CX_ROSTER_RULES_VIEW as m inner join (select rule, max(type) as type from CX_ROSTER_RULES_VIEW
    group by rule) p on m.rule = p.rule and m.type = p.type
```

don't sql on this machine, if the above don't work try this.  I will be able to test tomorrow if you don't have it complete.

```
select m.* from (select rule, max(type) as type from CX_ROSTER_RULES_VIEW
            group by rule) as p left join CX_ROSTER_RULES_VIEW  as m on p.rule = m.rule and p.type = m.type
```

it's pretty much the same, just want to see if a left join will do anything different.

Comment: Query is not giving correct results:
select main.* 
from CX_ROSTER_RULES_VIEW  main
inner join 
(select rule, max("Type") as type 
from CX_ROSTER_RULES_VIEW
group by rule) priority 
on main.rule = priority.rule 
and main."Type" = priority.type

Comment: Sorry I forget to put where clause. With where clause, I am getting the same result as my posted query.

Comment: what's the where clause for, if you want to do the where, you have to do it after the unique.  see edits

Comment: can you tell me if (select rule, max(type) as type from yourtable
group by rule) gives you the right rule and priority?

Comment: When I use only this query:
select rule, max("Type") as maxType 
from CX_ROSTER_RULES_VIEW
WHERE ( branch = 'Civil' AND category = 'C.M. (Civil)' AND sub_category = 'Pauper' )        
       OR ( branch = 'Civil' AND category = 'C.M. (Civil)' AND sub_category IS NULL )
        OR ( branch = 'Civil' AND category IS NULL AND sub_category IS NULL )
group by rule

I get this http://s33.postimg.org/m7dvi4cf3/Capture.png

Comment: No sir, your recent query is also generating same output. 'Day Rules' is not appearing. It appears if I add it in Rule1 or Rule2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select v.* from 
CX_ROSTER_RULES_VIEW v join  
(select rule, max(type) as maxType from  CX_ROSTER_RULES_VIEW group by rule) M
on v.Rule = M.Rule and v.type = M.maxType
```

Comment: select v.* from 
CX_ROSTER_RULES_VIEW v,  
(select rule, max("Type") as maxType from  CX_ROSTER_RULES_VIEW group by rule) M
where v.Rule = M.Rule and v."Type" = M.maxType
AND (( branch = 'Civil' AND category = 'C.M. (Civil)' AND sub_category = 'Pauper' )        
       OR ( branch = 'Civil' AND category = 'C.M. (Civil)' AND sub_category IS NULL )
  OR ( branch = 'Civil' AND category IS NULL AND sub_category IS NULL ) )

Rule "Day Rules" missing from output.

Comment: The query you've pasted is different to mine. Is my query giving you a more or less correct answer? I'm guessing you want to filter it further. If so, try putting the whole query inside a bracket.

Comment: Please do not use the legacy comma join syntax. The ANSI join syntax is much clearer (especially when you want to do outer joins).

Comment: Thanks @MT0. Made changes.

Comment: Also, how is your query different than mine ?

Comment: I used WHERE clause with your query as  below:
select v.* from 
CX_ROSTER_RULES_VIEW v join  
(select rule, max("Type") as maxType from  CX_ROSTER_RULES_VIEW group by rule) M
on v.Rule = M.Rule and v."Type" = M.maxType
WHERE ( branch = 'Civil' AND category = 'C.M. (Civil)' AND sub_category = 'Pauper' )        
       OR ( branch = 'Civil' AND category = 'C.M. (Civil)' AND sub_category IS NULL )
        OR ( branch = 'Civil' AND category IS NULL AND sub_category IS NULL )
and it is giving me as result as mine posted query.
[Link](http://s33.postimg.org/m7dvi4cf3/Capture.png)

Comment: "Day Rules" is missing.

Comment: 'Day Rules' is missing before you add the where clause? Can you paste the output for your query without the where clause.

Comment: Without WHERE clause, I am getting 18 records and Day Rules is part of it.

Comment: I'm guessing you're expecting 'Day Rules' To come in the last part of your where clause. You can confirm this with the query `select * from CX_ROSTER_RULES_VIEW where Rule = 'Day Rules' and branch = 'Civil' AND category IS NULL AND sub_category IS NULL`. Does this return a record for you????

Comment: I want Day Rule or any other rule to part of the output if is present in any of the given Type.

Comment: the query `select * from CX_ROSTER_RULES_VIEW where Rule = 'Day Rules' and branch = 'Civil' AND category IS NULL AND sub_category IS NULL`. Does this return a record for you???? If it doesn't, it means that for 'Day Rules', either category or sub category is not null and if you make it null the above query will work